# How to connect automatically to derby database server?

Tags: java, database, derby

> `java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException`: `java.net.ConnectException`: Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.

I am using Netbeans. If I go to the Services Tab and rightclick Java DB and start Server it works fine.

How can I do this programmatically at Runtime? I just need whatever method will start the Java DB Server.

```
public class login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public void close() {
        WindowEvent close = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(close);
    }

    public login() {
        try {
            initComponents();
            ((JLabel) jComboBox1.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            Calendar currentdate = new GregorianCalendar();
            int year1 = currentdate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            for (int i = 2000; i <= year1; i++) {
                jComboBox1.insertItemAt(i, jComboBox1.getItemCount());

            }
            NetworkServerControl server = new NetworkServerControl();
            server.start(null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } private void loginbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PreSchool";
            String user = "admin1";
            String pass = "admin1";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            Statement stat = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM admin1.login WHERE username ='" + usertxt.getText() + "'";
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                if ((usertxt.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("username"))) && (passtxt.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("password")))) {
                    switch (rs.getString("department")) {
                        case "0": {
                            manager man = new manager();
                            man.setVisible(true);
                            break;
                        }
                        case "1": {
                            program pr = new program();
                            pr.setVisible(true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
        }

    }
```

and this is derby.log:

```
An exception was thrown during network server startup. org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.DRDAServerStarter.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.start(Unknown Source)
    at login.<init>(login.java:33)
    at login$3.run(login.java:231)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.DRDAServerStarter$1.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006470/derby-automatically-start-server-within-java-application-and-connect-to-database?rq=1

Comment: not worked again. do u have any example ?

Comment: NetworkServerControl server = new NetworkServerControl();
server.start (null);     and i added it to constructor but i get the same message error .

Comment: add your source code which you have tried.

Comment: i edited it in my question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!